Using HashLocationStrategy in Angular 18
How to implement HashLocationStrategy in Angular 18, since there is no App Module in Angular 18

The other solution also works, however it's not the easiest or preferred solution. provideRouter() can also simply be used together with withHashLocation().
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, withHashLocation } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes, withHashLocation())],
};


Refer the below app.config.ts file
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), provideRouter(routes), provideAnimationsAsync(), { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
};

